# GTK+ Appearance in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, themes, gtk

I changed my appearance in Kubuntu to "MS Windows 9x", but the GTK+ applications remain with the oxygen style. I know about  the "GTK+ Appearance" tab in the settings, but it has only 2 options - "oxygen-gtk" and "raleigh". How can I add "MS Windows 9x" to the available options for GTK apps?

Comment: Raleigh is much similar to windows 9x


there is no windows7 gtk3 theme available yet

Answer (score 2):

You can't unless you find a MS Windows 9x GTK theme. While KDE can use GTK themes, GTK cannot use KDE themes.